# Azure AD B2C Linkedin claims provider

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am implementing the Linkedin sign-up/sign-in via custom policies but when I click on the LinkedinExchange button, I get the following exception from the User Journey Player:

> An exception was caught when making a request to URL "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,formatted-name,email-address)" using method "Get". The exception status code was "ProtocolError" with the following message: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized..
>   The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Here is the ClaimsProvider for Linkedin I added:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <Domain>linkedin.com</Domain>
  <DisplayName>Linkedin</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="Linkedin-OAUTH">
      <DisplayName>Linkedin</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OAuth2" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ProviderName">linkedin</Item>
        <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization</Item>
        <Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken</Item>
        <Item Key="AccessTokenResponseFormat">json</Item>
        <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,formatted-name,email-address)?format=json</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item>
        <Item Key="client_id">XXXXXXXXXXXX</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_LinkedinSecret" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="id" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="emailAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="firstName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="lastName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="formattedName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="Linkedin" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="Linkedin" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Does someone see what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Try adding <Item Key="ClaimsEndpointAccessTokenName">oauth2_access_token</Item>

Comment: Thank you very much, adding the Item fixed the issue. Now I would like to understand the need to add this Item since the Linkedin documentation says it returns an 'access_token' field and when I execute the API calls, it indeed returns the field 'access_token' and not 'oauth2_access_token'. Nowhere in the azure B2C documentation I can see the field oauth2_access_token ...

Comment: oauth2 refers to the protocol being used, not to the name of the field, but all-in-all your feedback is on point, this (a long with a bunch of other things in custom policies) needs to be better documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add LinkedIn as an Identity Provider in Azure AD B2C via custom policies, make sure you have the following entry in the ClaimsProvider's `<Metadata>` section:

`<Item Key="ClaimsEndpointAccessTokenName">oauth2_access_token</Ite‌​m>`