# Access LinkedIn API for a user authenticated with Azure AD B2C?

Tags: linkedin-api, azure-ad-b2c

A user logs in via Azure AD B2C in a mobile app using Azure Mobile Services and approves the LinkedIn app, **is there a way with the LinkedIn API to fetch the users image?**

I don't seem to get any info from Azure AD B2C. Can I somehow get the token from LinkedIn via Azure AD B2C to use it in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, **Azure AD B2C does not support requesting any extra scopes or information from social identity providers.**

**Azure AD B2C is also unable to provide you with the social IdP's token so that you can query the social IdP for this information.**

You can request the former in the [Azure AD B2C feedback forum](https://aka.ms/aadb2cuv) or vote for an existing ask on the latter: [Return social IdP's native access tokens back to the app](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334347-return-social-idp-s-native-access-tokens-back-to-t)

That being said, **you might be able to implement the retrieve the user's LinkedIn picture via [Custom Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom)**. You would include `profile-picture` in the `ClaimsEndpoint` value of your policy (see this post for reference: [Azure AD B2C Linkedin claims provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45922492/azure-ad-b2c-linkedin-claims-provider)) and then map the picture-url claim from LinkedIn back to a [custom claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-create-custom-attributes-profile-edit-custom) in Azure AD B2C.